# What's the best way to check the network status in Android app

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm writting an android application which is communiating with web db very frequently.
Those communicating code snippets are running in the background thread such as AsyncTask.
As you know, all the asynctask should check the network status to prevent blocked device. Here is my question.
What's the best workaround checking the network status.
In my case, i'm checking the network status before entering the network layer.
Then, it gets so many boilerplate codes..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your asking, but if you want to know how to check if the device is connected to the internet use this snippet

```
    protected boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Enable NETWORK_STATE_ACCESS permission (not sure if any more permissions but that should be it if not check log cat to see)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isConnectedToInternet(Context context){

    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }

    }
    return false;
}
```

It will return boolean value true or false whether true means internet is connected false means internet not present.
you need to add 

in meanifest file which must be needed to access internet.